# if every exception catch should log it?

Tags: java, exception

some books mentioned that the followed mode is bad. It says every exception if be rethrowed shouldn't log it to avoid to dupliacte exception log.? any other issues?

I am confused that if I can't log any exception when rethrow it , if the issue exist?

or if I log it, I am confused if the too many log generated if everybody do it.

```
catch (NoUserException e) { 

    LOG.error("No user available", e); 

    throw new UserServiceException("No user available", e); 

}
```

the reference
http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/04/06/exception-handling-antipatterns.html#logAndThrow

Comment: Well, it depends on the design of your application. If you know the exception will be caught and logged in caller code, you do not need to log it when you rethrow it, since it duplicates information and generates useless overhead (logs are both time and space consuming). It can also introduces confusion for those who analyze the logs.

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez this is true only if you print the exact same thing over and over. But if you provide a good description of the error through the delegation process - it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the books you mentioned, but to me, as someone who'll have to debug the code and find the root cause of the bugs, I'd like to read about it later in the logs as close as possible to the place where it first triggered.

Comment: http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/04/06/exception-handling-antipatterns.html#logAndThrow

Comment: I don't mean to disrespect Tim McCune in any way, but I disagree. In the obviously wrong example that he provided, all that was printed to log was "blah blah blah" which, naturally, is not constructive. 
If you'll print Errors with a good description through the process of exception-delegation, then later, it'll make the work of a support-engineer much easier!

Answer (score 0):

Every LOG function have a switch to disable that log message so you have to LOG all exception if it is unexpected one. If you expected that exception, for example you check if the String is a number and you would like to know the result on exception, then you do not need to do the Log.

Comment: http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/04/06/exception-handling-antipatterns.html#logAndThrow

Answer (score 0):

As far as exceptions are concerned, the most important log message should be located in service layer. Important thing is keeping the whole stack trace so the issue can be easily located even after several rethrows. 
You can always put logs in all layers and manipulate logging level for certail layers to see only logs from layer you are currently debugging/working on. Other logs can be set to OFF. Read documentation for your favorite logger to learn more about that.

Comment: When you construct exception using constructor that takes (Exception e) as a parameter you should keep the whole stack trace. That's what I meant. You can change logging lever for some packages using logging framework config file.